# Как сделать так, чтобы объект менял положение если на него навести курсор?

Tags: python, tkinter

В моем случае кнопка, при наведении у меня происходит однократное перемещение , опосля он при наведении не меняет позицию. Ошибок нет, но я думаю что чего-то не хватает, но не знаю чего...

```
import tkinter as tk
import random as rand

window = tk.Tk()
window.title('')
window.geometry('300x300')


def on_enter(event):
    button.place(x=x, y=y)


x = rand.randint(0, 283)
y = rand.randint(0, 283)

button = tk.Button(window, text='Move')
button.place(x=0, y=0)

button.bind('<Enter>', on_enter)

window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Переменные `x` и `y` у вас инициализируются один раз при старте программы, поэтому при каждом наведении кнопка остается на одном и том же месте (перемещается на одно и то же место).

Нужно сделать, чтобы при каждом наведении на кнопку получались новые случайные координаты, для этого перенесите инициализацию переменных `x` и `y` в обработчик события наведения:

```
def on_enter(event):
    x = rand.randint(0, 283)
    y = rand.randint(0, 283)
    button.place(x=x, y=y)
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное!

Comment: @Polestra если ответ помог, вы можете отметить его принятым, для этого поставьте галку слева от ответа.